# Normalizing data between 0 and 1

Tags: data-analysis

I've got some [data](http://pastebin.com/WiaifcLv) that I need to be normalized. I've tried several different ways I've found online, none of them work the way I'd like. I've tried `(x - mean) / standard_deviation`, where x is my value. I've also tried `(x - min) / (min - max)` as seen [here](http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/norm/norm_scale_between_0_and_1.htm). Those two seem to be the 2 standard way of normalizing data that I've seen.

What I'd like is to normalize the data between 1 and 0, cut it off at 3 decimal places, and still have a data make sense. Right now the numbers at the top are so large that they throw everything else off. The first 3 numbers are .8 somethings, but this it quickly drops off to .2 somethings and .1 somethings.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would it make sense to look at the Log of the data?

Comment: That helps, leaving the data looking like: http://pastebin.com/SRtDHpvm

Comment: How would you suggest to then make it fall into nice .9** .8** .7** .6** ... buckets?

Comment: I'd be more interested in the trend of the data.  It looks linear to me - is it?  That might help guide you.

Comment: Nah, it's not. There's still this long tail of small values, with a head of larger values above 10.

Comment: Have you considered a log-log plot to see if this behaves as $y=x^{\alpha}$?

Comment: Well, this data changes day by day, staying roughly similar. My goal is to write a function to place it into buckets of .9 .8 .7 for a team to analyze, where each bucket has about the same amount of items in it.

Comment: Then place it in buckets of $10^{0.9}$, $10^{0.8}$, etc.